# ASP.NET Core 2.0 - Multi-tenant JWT Signing Key

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, jwt

I'm building a web API in ASP.NET Core 2.0 and am using JWT as the authentication mechanism. So, I'd usually have some code like the following in **Startup.ConfigureServices**():

```
...
string secret = configuration.GetSection("TokenAuthentication:Secret").Value;
var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(secret));
services.AddAuthentication(o =>
{
    o.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    o.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
})

.AddJwtBearer(o =>
{
    o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,
        ValidateIssuer = true,
        ValidIssuer = configuration.GetSection("TokenAuthentication:Issuer").Value,
        ValidateAudience = true,
        ValidAudience = configuration.GetSection("TokenAuthentication:Audience").Value,
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
    };
});
...
```

However, the secret varies for each tenant. So, ideally I'd lookup the secret from a database table ...

I'm struggling to see how to do this because the above code sets the secret when all the dependencies are registered - I need to do this on each request.

I wondered whether I was missing something simple - like a delegate that I can implement to do the secret lookup ... or whether I needed to roll my own JWT validator (not keen on this!)

Any help appreciated!

Comment: There is such delegate, named `IssuerSigningKeyResolver` (on `TokenValidationParameters`). There is also property IssuerSigningKey**s** on the same object, which allows you to provide multiple keys, of which one will be chosen based on key id specified in jwt token. This one is I'd say preferred to providing custom resolver.

Comment: Thanks Evk, The IssuerSigningKeyResolver delegate worked a treat